# Understanding 2D Array

Tags: python

With the help of the internet, I have written the following code to generate a 3x8 2D list with random numbers. I am not sure why row = "" has been used in the last line? Thanks.

```
import random
#create 3 by 8 2D list

rows = 3
cols = 8

#create a pre-initialised 2D List
my2DList = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]

#using nested loop insert random number between 1 and 9 to pre-initialised 2D list

for x in range(rows):
  for y in range(cols):
    my2DList[x][y] = random.randint(1,9)

#remove the last square bracket and the comma

row = ""

for x in range(rows):
  for y in range(cols):
    row = row + str(my2DList[x][y]) + ","
  row = row[:-1]
  print(row)
  row = ""
```

Comment: its just to clear the value of `row` for the next iteration. Its the same as defining row in the line under `for x in range(rows)`

Comment: Why not just loop `my2DList` and print the sublists like `print(','.join([str(i) for i in sublist]))`

Comment: The first one is used to have an empty string. So in the line `row = row + str(my2DList[x][y]) + ","` you won't get `NameError`. The second one is called resting. You just empty the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `row` is a temporary "placeholder" variable that holds the row you're currently building. Therefore, after every loop, you "reset" `row` by setting it equal to `""`. Otherwise, each new "row" would be made up of all the rows before it in addition to the current row, since it only gets larger and not smaller.

Comment: Hi, I am now trying to create unique random numbers instead of just random numbers and trying random.sample(range(1,10),9) but it's populating a lot of grids instead of 8 cols and 3 rows with unique random numbers. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: @John ask a new question. I will need to see code for the new version, which we can't do in comments.

Comment: Please see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619947/generate-unique-random-numbers-using-2d-array-list-in-python