# Generate unique random numbers using 2D array/list in Python

Tags: python

The following code would generate random numbers between 1 and 9 in a 3x8 2D array.

```
import random
#create 3 by 8 2D list

rows = 3
cols = 8

#create a pre-initialised 2D List
my2DList = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]

#using nested loop insert random number between 1 and 9 to pre-initialised 2D list

for x in range(rows):
  for y in range(cols):
    my2DList[x][y] = random.randint(1,9)

#remove the last square bracket and the comma

row = ""

for x in range(rows):
  for y in range(cols):
    row = row + str(my2DList[x][y]) + ","
  row = row[:-1]
  print(row)
  row = ""
```

I am now trying to create unique random numbers instead of just random numbers and trying `random.sample(range(1,10),9)` but it's populating a lot of grids instead of 8 cols and 3 rows with unique random numbers. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: please update the original code, so that there is an entire sample of code that one can run to see the issue. Also please print some sample output, and describe a bit better what you want it to be instead.

Comment: `[random.sample(range(1,10), cols) for _ in range(rows)]`?

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but could you also post the output of the program